# Improper Multivariable Integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How can I find the values of $\alpha$ for which the following integrals (in $\mathbb{R}^n $ ) converge ?

1. $\int_{|\vec{x}|\geq 1 } \frac{ln(|\vec{x}|^3 )}{|\vec{x}|^\alpha} d\vec{x} $
2. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n } \frac{sin(|\vec{x}|)}{|\vec{x}|^\alpha} d\vec{x} $

I guess the thing is we need to calculate the limit form of these integrals, in some other coordinate system, where $r= ||\vec{x}|| $ ... I can't figure out what will be that Jacobian in this case and can't understand how to solve these questions

Will you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\def\vol{{\rm vol}}\vol_{n-1}(rS^{n-1}) = 2\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)} r^{n-1} =: \beta_{n-1} r^{n-1}$, we have $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$ \begin{align*}
  \int_{\abs x \ge 1} \frac{\log \abs x^3}{\abs x^\alpha}\, dx 
  &= \int_{1}^\infty \int_{rS^{n-1}} \frac{\log r^3}{r^\alpha}\, dS(x)\, dr\\
  &= \beta_{n-1} \int_1^\infty \frac{\log r^3}{r^\alpha} r^{n-1}\, dr\\
  &= 3\beta_{n-1}\int_1^\infty {r^{ n - 1-\alpha}\cdot \log r}\, dr
\end{align*}
This converges if $n-1-\alpha < -1$, that is $\alpha > n$.

For the second case, arguing along the same lines, we have
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{\sin\abs x}{\abs x^\alpha}\, dx
  &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin r}{r^\alpha}\beta_{n-1} r^{n-1}\, dr\\
  &= \int_0^\infty \sin r \cdot r^{n-1-\alpha}\, dr
\end{align*}
This converges "at $\infty$" if $n-1-\alpha < -1$, that is $\alpha > n$, and "at 0" if $n-\alpha> -1$ (note that $\sin r\cdot r^{n-1-\alpha} = \frac{\sin r}r \cdot r^{n-\alpha}$, that is if $\alpha < n+1$. So we must have $\alpha \in (n, n+1)$.

Comment: Hi @martini, thanks for your answer. 
I can't understand the equality:
 $ \int_{\abs x \ge 1} \frac{\log \abs x^3}{\abs x^\alpha}\, dx 
  = \int_{1}^\infty \int_{rS^{n-1}} \frac{\log r^3}{r^\alpha}\, dS(x)\, dr\\...$ (i.e. - I can't understand how you passed from an integral over some region to two integrals , one over $1 ,\infty$ and the other over $rS^n $ (why $rS^n$?)

Thanks !

Comment: Note that $\{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \left| x\right| \ge 1\} = \biguplus_{r \ge 1} rS^{n-1}$, where $S^{n-1}$ denotes the unit sphere, i. e. the set of vectors with unit length.

Comment: Hmmm... when writing $r\cdot S^{n-1} $ do you mean pointwise multiplication ? i.e. - $(xr| x\in S^{n-1} ) $ ?

Comment: and why did you put $dS(x)$ ? why does this volume element depend on $x$ ?

Comment: (1) Yes, $rS^{n-1} = \{rx \mid x \in S^{n-1}$. And by writing $dS(x)$ I tried to make explicit that the variable with respect to which we integrate is $x$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I stil can't understand this. $x$ in our case is a vector. So you actually mean that the interior integral represents $n$ different integrals ? (i.e.- $dx_1 dx_2 ...$  ? ) .... Hope I am getting this correct. Thanks !

Comment: No, it represents (if you want to say it like that) $n-1$ 1-dimensional integrals, as a sphere is a $n-1$-dimensional object. I wanted to mark that we integrate with respect to the surface measure of the sphere.

Comment: ok. I thi nk I got it. thanks

Comment: Can you please explain to me how did you get the convergence at $\infty$ of the second integral ? Thanks !

Comment: The second integral converges at infty (in the Lebesgue sense) if the exponent or $r$ is less then $-1$, as the sine is bounded ...